# After CreateProcessWithLogonW switch language with alt shift stops working

Tags: winapi

I encountered a strange problem:
When our application spawns child process with CreateProcessWithLogonW 
switch language with alt-shift stops working in the windows of the new process. 
What might be the problem?  The OS is XP SP3.  The same setup is ok on Win 7.

Additional thing I discovered: This problem only occurs on Win XP Hebrew. 
On English XP it works fine.

Comment: Considering that XP SP4 doesn't exist, perhaps that's your problem?

Comment: No kidding.  I'd guess at the LOGON_WITH_PROFILE option missing.

Comment: A single-digit typo doesn't deserve mockery.

Comment: LOGON_WITH_PROFILE present  but maybe I should do something else to actually load the profile.

Comment: @SparcU please show some source code...

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant has said `CreateProcessWithLogonW` requires the `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` to be set as `dwLogonFlags`  which is the fourth argument of the function in order to load the user registry hive into HKEY_USERS. This will ensure that access to information in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry key will produce results that are consistent with a normal interactive logon.

Alternately you can call the `LoadUserProfile` function beforecalling  `CreateProcessWithLogonW`.

Registry settings you will want to verify exist for the user whose profile you are loading include

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle]
"Hotkey"="3"
"Language Hotkey"="3"
"Layout Hotkey"="3"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload]
"1"="00000809"
"2"="e00e0804"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar]
"ShowStatus"=dword:00000000"
```

The values of `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle]` are

- 1 Key Sequence enabled; use Left-ALT+SHIFT to switch between locales.
- 2 Key Sequence enabled; use CTRL+SHIFT to switch between locales.
- 3 Key Sequences disabled.
- 4 If the default locale is Thai, the accent grave key toggles input locales; otherwise key    sequences are disabled.

The values of `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload]` are listed [here](http://www.easydesksoftware.com/keyboard.htm) under the KeyName column.

The values of `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar]` are

- 0 Floating on desktop
- 4 Docked on the taskbar
- 3 when set to Hidden which is the default.

Relevant resources include

- [Similar Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595176/createprocesswithlogonw-problems-need-to-launch-sub-processes-with-the-same)
- [CreateProcessWithLogonW function MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Managed CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://geekswithblogs.net/khanna/archive/2005/02/09/22430.aspx)

Comment: Thanks . I will check the registry settings.

Comment: I did use LoadUserProfile but it did not help

Comment: I use remoteApp and put `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\LangBar]` part in logon script but no luck...Thanks anyway!